# A opening bid of 1Club if followed by 1Diamond

Tags: bridge

A opening bid of 1 Club if followed by 1 Diamond in Bridge shows no majors and 6-7 point, is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, no 4 card major...

Comment: No worries. You can use the "edit" button to edit your post whenever you want.

Comment: WHAT BIDDING SYSTEM?  If you don't know enough to answer that, please let us know what country you are in, and then we can answer based on the most common bidding system(s) in that country.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about std american or ilk, no it is not correct. You could have a hand with 5 diamonds and a 4 card major which responds 1D first. The point range could be anything, from min 6 pts to slam looking...

Answer (score 2):

For the time being we would assume you are playing a Green system similar to SAYC.

There are mainly 3 ways of responding to a natural / semi-natural (2+) non-forcing 1C opening:

1. Up-the-line: You bid your 5-card suits if you have one. Otherwise you simply bid your lowest 4-card suit. Under this method, a 1D opening does NOT deny holding a 4-card Major - you may have zero, one or two 4-card Majors. Say you hold: 963 KJ87 QJ53 A8 , you will usually respond 1D. Opener may either raise, bid his own 4-card Major, rebid Clubs or just bid 1NT. This is very natural and practically does not require extra gadgets.
2. Walsh: You always bypass any length in Diamond in favour of a Major suit response, unless you hold game-forcing value. Therefore hands like 9 KJ87 QJT753 Q8 are still responded with a 1H, despite you holding much longer Diamond. This has the advantage of letting you find any 4-4 Major fits half a round earlier, but at the cost of bidding space: you are making a higher-level response (1M consumes more bidding space than 1D) which does not contain more information (Under this scheme, 1M response happens more often than 1D) than a lower response.
3. Transfer Walsh: In order to solve the dilemma between MAFIA (MAjor FIrst Always) and bidding space consumption, Transfer Walsh is designed. You bid 1D to show Hearts, 1H to show Spades and 1S to show Diamond or other minor-oriented hands. This keeps your bidding low while at the same time allowing you to prioritize showing Majors. However, this needs extra agreements with your partner about continuations, and your partnership must be able to cope with interference.

Therefore in response to your question:

Q1: ... shows no [4-card] Major...

A1: Not necessarily. Given your question suggesting 1D denying Major, I assume you are playing Method 2. It usually denies 4-card Major, but only usually, not always. A scenario that you can still hold 4-card Major is that you have game-forcing values and your Diamond is worth mentioning, e.g. x AQxx KQJxxx Qx . You can respond 1D first, and upon opener rebidding 1NT you can reverse into 2H, or if he bids 1S you can make a XYZ or 4SF to further investigate into an ideal game or slam.

Q2: ... and 6-7 points...

A2: No, suit responses are unlimited. Your next call will most likely reveal what strength your hand has. A weak hand will pass, make a preference or rebid his own suit, a stronger hand will move on to game or make forcing bids to find out more about opener's hand.

Comment: I liked your answer...I am writing from New Delhi, India.  I am playing Standard American,  2 over 1, game force. I agree, with fewer points I would bid my 4 card Heart over my 5 carder diamond, looking for a major fit.  But with less then 10 points I don't think I will be able to show my diamonds at all unless partner bids.  I play with this Old School lady who says a bid of 1D over 1C does show 6-7 points only.  I am meeting her again today, will seek more clarifications.  Thanks Again...

Comment: Then yes you are playing Walsh. You are correct that you may not have a chance to show Diamonds at all, but who cares about minor anyways.

Comment: Also, if the lady insists 1D shows 6-7 points only, you may ask her how you should respond with these hands: 1) xx Kxx AQ9xxx Ax ; 2) Kxx x KQJxxx xxx. Hand 1 is enough to force game but is not suitable for a Soloway jump shift (suit not solid enough); hand 2 is not 6-7, is not enough for a game force and can make you miss a light game if responded 1NT.

Comment: The only other think which irks me is that while searching for a Major fit using this system I am by-passing my 5 card minor.  Though I might I have 5 cards in the minor now I cant bid it even with opening hand values ie 13-14 points as it would be a reverse showing 17 or more points, so in a way I cant show a 5 card minor and a 4 card major unless its the other way round, is that correct? I hope I have been lucid enough in my query.

Comment: And lastly as a somewhat beginner what are the conventions you think I need to know? My Bridge "Guru" has this to say :

Comment: Based on frequency of use, among the top 10 conventions would be:
 
Stayman and Jacoby Transfers,Takeout and Negative Doubles,Help Suit Game Tries,New Minor Forcing, Michaels and Unusual Notrump
Jacoby 2 Notrump
Splinters, Notrump interference (DONT, etc)

Comment: Many Thanks, My enter key is making me add comments which I dont want to do :)

Comment: sorry i am wrong with my above comment i can and should bid it...it would be a appropriate 2 over 1 bid. But what if i had 10 point, then I couldn't and at times I cant bid it as it becomes a reversal...complicated.

Comment: I think you might have mixed it up: a reverse by responder only shows game-going values, it never promises an enormous hands like 17+. With ~13 values you can bid Diamonds first, planning on introducing your Major later. If you don't hold values to go for a game, just do not bother bidding Diamond at all.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have mixed it up.  As an opener if I bid 1D first and followed it up with a lets say 1S (with my partner / or opponents bidding 1H in between), that would be a reverse ??? showing 17+ points.  So that means if I have a 5 card Minor 4 card Major, 13 -14 points and am the opener, I cant really show the 5 - 4 to my partner unless I bid 1NT and then bid my 4 card Major. I probably need 5 cards to bid that, do I ? Sorry, but I am a bit confused.

Comment: Lastly, If I open 1D, LHO bids 1S, my partner goes 2C,  then with a minimum hand and no support for clubs, only a 5 carder diamond, what would I bid??? How many points would a 2NT bid show? Many thanks...

Comment: For the time being we will not deal with interference. Reverse is a bid in a higher-rank new suit that bypasses the lower-rank suit bid by you. If you open 1D and rebid 1S, it is not a reverse since it does not bypass the lower-rank suit, i.e. 1S is lower than 2D. Your 1S bid is just a simple bid up the line and does not constitute a reverse. This may have gone a bit too far away from your original question. You may open a new question and all of us will be pleased to answer you.